# React-Native open "My Files" app at specific directory

Tags: android, react-native

I have used Linking api to open other apps such as Phone or Email, but how do I open the file explorer / internal storage / my files app? And how would I specifically open it to the downloads folder directory?

I have tried the following code but it returns a rejected promise.

```
Linking.openURL('myfiles://app');
```

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: I am in need of this now.